# Import .bas file using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

My goal is to create a VBScript that automatically import a .bas file to the Worksheet named "INPUT". (As you can see in the picture below)

[image]

I tried to write this but it seems like the compiler doesn't like it.

> VBProject.VBComponents.Item("INPUT").Import(PathName & "updateInputSheet.bas")

I tried a lot of different code but still, doesn't work...

Best regards,

Comment: Hallo, what's the error massage?

Comment: @TSion.D.P Object Required : 'VBProject' Code: 800A01A8

Comment: That means you didn't initiate your VBProject variable, try to look for an example on how to use VBProject here on SO or google